# How to fix uri for `http.server.requests` metric for /token endpoint of spring-authorization-server?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-micrometer, spring-authorization-server

I'm using Spring Authorization Server, and didn't notice that `http.server.requests` metric contains `/oauth2/token` `uri` tag.

But I've noticed during debugging of `WebMvcMetricsFilter` that the metric is actually counted, but the `uri` tag is `root`, because `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo` returns `null` for requests on `/oauth2/token`

Why doesn't that work by defualt?

Also didn't notice anything about metrics in docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/overview.html

Any idea how to fix `uri` tag for `http.server.requests` metric for standard `/oauth2/token` endpoint?